# NotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported. Why?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, exception

There is an `AdminService` class that inherits from `UserService`. `UserService` has a `changePassword` method. Accordingly, this method works fine when I enter a valid `login`, but as soon as I enter an invalid `login` my error handler does not work. Why?

In addition to the `if` construct, I also tried `try catch`, but the result is one.

I am writing a project using Spring MVC + REST + Spring Security + Jpa + Hibernate + PostgreSQL

UserService:

```java
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {


    // Fields
    //
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    // Injects are here
    //
    @Autowired
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setPasswordEncoder(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }


    // Методы
    //
    // 
    public User changePassword(String login, String newPass) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = getUserDataByLogin(login);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("not found" + login);
        } else {
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newPass));
            return userRepository.save(user);
        }
    }
```

AdminController:

```java
@PutMapping("/change/password")
    User changePassword(@RequestParam String login, @RequestParam String newPass) {
        return userService.changePassword(login, newPass);
    }
```

UserRepo:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    // Найти пользователя по Login (логин универсален)
    User getByLogin(String login);

}
```

```java
2020-05-14 22:25:30.094  WARN 21000 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported]
```

Comment: If you _must_ have your repository and encoder to operate (you do), then you should make them constructor parameters instead of setters. Additionally, don't use `equals` to check for null, since it will always throw NPE if true! Instead, use `user == null`.

Comment: Sorry. I am Adding errors log in quest.. And when I change to `user == null`
 `HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'PUT' not supported`

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking

```
if (user.equals(null)) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("not found" + login);
    }
```

When user is null, so you are trying to access to equals in a null object, this throw exception, to compare if null is better do it by this way:

```
    if(user == null) {
     //
    }
```

Comment: Sorry. I am Adding errors log in quest.. And when I change to `user == null`
 `HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'PUT' not supported`

Comment: Try adding @PutMapping("/change/password", 
    produces ={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

Comment: I am adding now `@PutMapping(value = "/change/password", produces ={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})` and it dont help